# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getUnit_id() from the type Officer

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I am trying to insert the values from this code below:

```
public int create(Officer officer) {
     String sql = "insert into officer values(" + officer.getOfficer_id() + ", " + officer.getCollege_id() + ", " + Officer.getUnit_id() + ", " + officer.getRole_id() + ")";
     return template.update(sql);
}
```

Comment: @ayanth add the exception you're getting, project configuration

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getUnit_id() from the type Officer

Comment: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "create"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a compilation error. getUnit_id is not a static method , so you need to call it using an instance of Officer.

`public int create(Officer officer) {
     String sql = "insert into officer values(" + officer.getOfficer_id() + ", " + officer.getCollege_id() + ", " + officer.getUnit_id() + ", " + officer.getRole_id() + ")";
     return template.update(sql);
}`